# How replicate eigen::matrix dynamically

Tags: c++, eigen

During calculating the distance matrix between two feature maps.

```
A:(M,1)
B:(N,1)
```

I want to repeat B columns to equal A rows.

It is simple in NumPy:

```
A = np.random,rand(100, 1)
B = np.random.rand(88, 1)
np.repeat(B, A.shape[0], axis=1)
```

But in c++ Eigen, not work for dynamically assigning repeated shapes.

```
MatrixXi A = MatrixXi::Random(100,1);
MatrixXi B = MatrixXi::Random(88,1);

B.replicate<1, A.rows()>(); // This will cause failure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to achieve the same effect as the python's numpy version in C++ would be:

```
B.replicate<1, 100>();
```

The above will do the replication as you want.
Or you can use:

```
B.replicate(1, A.rows());
```

Comment: This is not what I want, rows of A and B are unknown.

Comment: @ZhengfangXin For that you can instead use `B.replicate(1, A.rows());` . They both use the same function template `replicate<>`.